# Display json response in to UILabel

Tags: ios, json, uilabel

My json Response is like this ..

```
{
sentdetails =     (
            {
        coursename = "Course Two";
        createddate = "05/12/2015 06:13 AM";
        currentprice = "2.00";
        "no_of_files" = 9;
        queryid = 36;
        querystatus = Open;
        submissionid = TSAb13d585e;
        testsaviornotes = None;
        title = Test;
        usernotes = rdgbv;
    }
);
status = Sucess;}
```

Now I am trying to display json data which is forth one namely "no_of_files" into `UILabel` and my code is like ..

```
NSMutableArray * aryy=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
     jsonDisplay = [aryy valueForKey:@"sentdetails"];
     NSLog(@"%@",jsonDisplay);
     NSLog(@"\n\n\n%@",aryy);

     SentItemDetailViewController *viewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SentItemDetailViewController"];

     viewController.numberofFiles = [[jsonDisplay objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"no_of_files"];
```

But the value for "num_of_files" can't store on `UILable` I don't know what's the problem behind that.

Comment: no_of_files is integer value , use stringwithFormat to convert it as string value  and set as label text

Comment: numberofFiles is of which type ?

Comment: integer type @MuhammadAdnan

Comment: yes that's the thing which i forgot ...
Thank You 
@MuhammadAdnan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSNumber * num = [[jsonDisplay objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"no_of_files"];
viewController.numberofFiles.text = [num stringValue];
```

Comment: Yes you are genius @Leo . its work for me..
really i appreciate your answer..
Thank you so much LEO

Answer (score 2):

if `numberofFiles` is a `UILabel` you should write `viewController.numberofFiles.text` so:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
jsonDisplay = dict[@"sentdetails"];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonDisplay);
NSLog(@"\n\n\n%@",dict);
SentItemDetailViewController *viewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SentItemDetailViewController"];
viewController.numberofFiles.text = [[jsonDisplay objectAtIndex:0][@"no_of_files"] stringValue];
```

Comment: it's not work for me .... getting null value
please tell me another thing if you know...Thank YOu @Gonji Dev

Comment: You said that numberofFiles is a integer..so this is not gonna work. Where exactly are you setting the UILabel value?

Comment: Now its woking for me Gonji Dev.. 
above answer of Leo's are work for me.
and Thank You so much for your suggestion @Gonji Dev

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
viewController.numberofFiles.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[jsonDisplay objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"no_of_files"]];
```

As I can notice that value for key no_of_files is not nsstring. Also need to give valuye to .text not label. :)

Comment: yes i notice for nsstring ,and i have changed it to nsstring as you suggest me but still not getting value.

Comment: it seems you are trying to set label text of some other view, if yes that's not possible here. you need to set in that particular viewcontroller only. Assign value to string object that is property synthesised.

Comment: yes after that i have use this code...

NSNumber * num = [[jsonDisplay objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"no_of_files"];
         viewController.numberofFiles = [num stringValue];

and its work for me. 
and Thank you so much @sschunara for your good suggetion's 
Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0):

using **Alamofire**
first you have to convert data(NSData) into string .

```
    var jsonString:String = ""
    var parseDataToShow:Data?
    @IBOutlet weak var lblToPrintDetails: UILabel!

 Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

  debugPrint(response.result.value!)
// data form
  let jsonData1 = response.data 

   jsonString = String(data: parseDataToShow!, encoding: .utf8)!

    // you can print converted string data

    print("JsonString = \(jsonString)")
  self.lblToPrintDetails.text = jsonString

 })
```